# jQuery location picker API doesn't return address components for some location

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jQuery location picker API With Map view. The location picker API doesn't work for some location addresses.

If I give input for location name as "The vintage gulmarg" in the location field, The location field restores the previous formatted address and the google places API doesn't return any address components, whereas the same location name is located perfectly on the map.

I have faced this issue in the jQuery location picker plugin itself. Please check the below URL and scroll down to see the option "Binding UI with the widget" and type the location as "The Vintage Gulmarg" in the location field:-

http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/.

Comment: can you post  the code ?

Comment: U can refer this Jquery plugin url: http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/  and find this option "Binding UI with the widget" .